# Visual studio 2017 upgrade unattended

Tags: powershell

I have VS 2017 15.6.7 installed ,and i would like to upgrade it to VS 2017-15.9.11 using power shell in unattended mode .
I tried to use the following command:

But nothing occurred.

```
"Start-Process -filepath "C:\2017 - 15.9.11\vs_Professional.exe" -ArgumentList "--norestart --quiet" -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden"
```

Comment: Do you run that command with quotes around it? Have you tried removing them?

Comment: i ran  without them..